# NAudio multiple Input to multiple Output

Tags: c#, io, naudio

I have multiple audio Input

- 1 WaveProvider from a File
- 1 WaveProvider from a SpeechSynthesizer

And I want to forward these WaveProvider to multiple audio Output WaveOut (to multiple DeviceNumber).

But I have 3 issues:

1. Some WaveOut seems wrong and hang forever
2. WaveOut.Play() seems synchronized
3. If I put them in Tasks the first Task start playing on device then it is interrupted by the other Task on the other Device

Does anybody have a sample code working correctly ?

Here is a sample that do not work with 2 tasks:

```
Buffer = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
WaveOut = new WaveOut();
WaveOut.DeviceNumber = device;
WaveOut.Init(Buffer);

...

Buffer.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
WaveOut.Play();
```

I did't find sample playing with all WaveOut. According to NAudio author, I shouldn't have to use Tasks but I don"t know how to set multiple output and input in magic mixer class ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WaveOut is Synchronous and Exclusive a workaround is to use FunctionCallback to set WaveOut in a Background Thread

```
WaveOutSpeech = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
WaveOutSpeech.DeviceNumber = device;
```

If you still need synchronous code you must:

- Run this code in a N Tasks
- Wait for one of them
- Control WaveOut flow

Here is a sample:

```
private void RunSession(WaveOut WaveOut, WaveStream stream, string match) {

  played.Add(match);

  WaveOut.Init(stream);
  WaveOut.Play();
  while (stream.CurrentTime < stream.TotalTime && played.Contains(match)) {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
  WaveOut.Stop();
  stream.Dispose();

  played.Remove(match);
}
```

The 3rd parameter match is the name of the streamed item. This allow stopping loop before end.